# Get Running Name App above Android 4

Tags: android, task, classname

I'm trying to get the Name of running apps, but it seems that it doesn't work for Android 5.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
public class Check extends BroadcastReceiver {
Tiempo tt=new Tiempo();
public final String TAG = "CRAR"; // CheckRunningApplicationReceiver

public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent) {


try {

// Using ACTIVITY_SERVICE with getSystemService(String)
// to retrieve a ActivityManager for interacting with the global system state.

ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) aContext
.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

// Return a list of the tasks that are currently running,
// with the most recent being first and older ones after in order.
// Taken 1 inside getRunningTasks method means want to take only
// top activity from stack and forgot the olders.

List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am
.getRunningTasks(1);

//
for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : alltasks) {

// These are showing current running activity in logcat with
// the use of different methods

Log.i(TAG, "===============================");
Log.i(TAG, "aTask.baseActivity: "
+ aTask.baseActivity.flattenToShortString());
Log.i(TAG, "aTask.baseActivity: "
+ aTask.baseActivity.getClassName());
Log.i(TAG, "aTask.topActivity: "
+ aTask.topActivity.flattenToShortString());
Log.i(TAG, "aTask.topActivity: "
+ aTask.topActivity.getClassName());
Log.i(TAG, "===============================");
if(aTask.topActivity.getClassName().compareTo("com.jrdcom.launcher.Launcher")==0){
tt.Detener();
}else{
tt.Contar();
Log.e("tiempo encendido2", String.valueOf(tt.getSegundos()));
}
}

} catch (Throwable t) {
Log.i(TAG, "Throwable caught: "
+ t.getMessage(), t);
}

}
}
```

When I run this code, the logcat shows this:

```
6240-6240/com.example.usuario.proy I/SR﹕ ===============================
02-06 16:30:11.100    6240-6240/com.example.usuario.proy I/SR﹕ aTask.baseActivity: com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
02-06 16:30:11.100    6240-6240/com.example.usuario.proy I/SR﹕ aTask.baseActivity: com.android.launcher2.Launcher
02-06 16:30:11.100    6240-6240/com.example.usuario.proy I/SR﹕ aTask.topActivity: com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
02-06 16:30:11.100    6240-6240/com.example.usuario.proy I/SR﹕ aTask.topActivity: com.android.launcher2.Launcher
02-06 16:30:11.100    6240-6240/com.example.usuario.proy I/SR﹕ ===============================
```

Asyou can see, it show only the launcher, but there is no App name in Android 5. For Android 4 it works perfectly.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, but in the ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo that I'm using it says that  works with ComponentName, but it's not working. Also I've tryed to use other class names like PackageManager.

Comment: I don't see anything about ComponentName for `getRunningTasks()`, see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)   Also notice that it's been deprecated in Lollipop, and also that it's never been supported for core logic in an app.......

Comment: Thank you, but I also used getRunningTasks() , but nothing changes.